Compilation and linking errors using std::stacktrace
I am working in Fedora 39 Linux, and would like to start using std::stacktrace from C++23, which is available in libstdc++.
Unfortunately, I bumped in some errors even with the simplest example:
#include <stacktrace>

int main() {
    (void)to_string( std::stacktrace::current() );
}

In Clang, I get a long compilation error
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/stacktrace:644:3: error: no matching function for call to 'operator delete'
  644 |                 _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE (static_cast<void*>(_M_frames),
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  645 |                                           _M_capacity * sizeof(value_type));
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/stacktrace:599:35: note: expanded from macro '_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE'
  599 | # define _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE __builtin_operator_delete
      |                                   ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/new:144:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'const std::nothrow_t' for 2nd argument
  144 | void operator delete(void*, const std::nothrow_t&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
      |      ^                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...

And in GCC, the compilation goes fine, but I get linking errors:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/ccXWeU5s.o: in function `std::stacktrace_entry::_S_init()':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/stacktrace:164: undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_create_state'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/ccXWeU5s.o: in function `std::stacktrace_entry::_M_get_info(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, int*) const':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/stacktrace:196: undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_pcinfo'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/stacktrace:206: undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_syminfo'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/ccXWeU5s.o: in function `std::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<std::stacktrace_entry> >::current(std::allocator<std::stacktrace_entry> const&)':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/stacktrace:259: undefined reference to `__glibcxx_backtrace_simple'

Fortunately, both errors can be reproduced on godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aovffv81s
How one can fix these errors?

What makes you think it's supported? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23 -- which may or may not be correct -- says something about gcc-14, and "partial" on gcc-12 (I don't know how to read the asterisk, though). So, I'd guess 13 is also "partial". Clang is completely red. Your code not compiling makes me think cppreference might not be completely off track...

Does this help? How can I generate a C++23 stacktrace with GCC 12.1?

@BoP, thanks, indeed -lstdc++_libbacktrace option resolves the issue with GCC. And is it possible to make it work in Clang with libstdc++ as well?

You need -fsized-deallocation on Clang (plus -lstdc++_libbacktrace, of course, and maybe -no-pie).

Thanks, it works: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vhxTxv45d

Also try -lstdc++exp
